# Can take ssh from windows machine but couldn't ping back from raspberry pi

Tags: networking, wifi, raspbian-stretch, ping

I have created a network using a wifi router with 2 raspberry pi devices (stretch OS) and one windows 10 machine.

**Windows ipconfig:**

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f0cf:c120:e272:5687%12
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 190.160.1.2
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 190.160.1.1
```

**RPI device -1**

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:ed:64:ff  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 28  bytes 2372 (2.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 28  bytes 2372 (2.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 190.160.1.101  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 190.160.1.255
        inet6 fe80::eeaf:3b9d:fb9a:bf4f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:b8:31:aa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 518  bytes 58281 (56.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 394  bytes 49746 (48.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

dhcpd.conf file for device 1

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=190.160.1.101/24
static routers=190.160.1.1
```

**RPI device -2**

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:47:b2:bb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 9  bytes 524 (524.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9  bytes 524 (524.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 190.160.1.102  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 190.160.1.255
        inet6 fe80::fbc5:984d:503a:4ced  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:12:e7:ee  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 460  bytes 55329 (54.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 344  bytes 54512 (53.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

dhcpd.conf file for device 2

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=190.160.1.102/24
static routers=190.160.1.1
```

/etc/network/interfaces for both RPI 1 and 2 are empty

I could ping the raspberry pi devices from the windows machine and can ssh the same. both raspberry pi device can ping each other too.

**PROBLEM IS**

I couldn't ping windows machine from the raspberry pi even though I took ssh from the windows machine.

I couldn't figure out what I am missing. If you need more detail please comment.

**Edit:**
[image: enabled the firewall rules as per Harvey's answer]

But still the ping from raspberry is not getting reply.

Answer (score 2):

You are using public ip addresses from 190.160.1.0/24 for your private local area network. Never do that, except you have rent this subnet from your internet provider for public use! It may confuse the router. Use instead reserved [ip addresses for private networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses), e.g. 192.168.1.0/24. This is the first step to reduce possible problems.